# Пытаюсь использовать phatomJS для скрина, но выдает ошибку Permission denied, как исправить?

Tags: php

Подключил phatomJS, но при его использовании выдает ошибку доступа, а логи;

```
[Sun May 12 13:08:29.851934 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 10772] [client 172.68.245.146:45558] AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Screen\\Exceptions\\PhantomJsException' with message 'sh: /var/www/sklad5379/data/www/САЙТ/scrinshooter/vendor/microweber/screen/bin/phantomjs: Permission denied' in /var/www/sklad5379/data/www/САЙТ/scrinshooter/vendor/microweber/screen/src/Capture.php:259
[Sun May 12 13:08:29.851984 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 10772] [client 172.68.245.146:45558] AH01215: Stack trace:
[Sun May 12 13:08:29.852079 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 10772] [client 172.68.245.146:45558] AH01215: #0 /var/www/sklad5379/data/www/САЙТ/scrinshooter/screenshot.php(28): Screen\\Capture->save('images/f4881cfc...')
[Sun May 12 13:08:29.852089 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 10772] [client 172.68.245.146:45558] AH01215: #1 {main}
[Sun May 12 13:08:29.852184 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 10772] [client 172.68.245.146:45558] AH01215:   thrown in /var/www/sklad5379/data/www/САЙТ/scrinshooter/vendor/microweber/screen/src/Capture.php on line 259
```

Там идет ошибка возвращаемого кода: Код ошибки - 126

На 259 строчке:

```
exec(sprintf("%s 2>&1", escapeshellcmd($command)), $output, $returnCode);

if ($returnCode !== 0) {
    throw new PhantomJsException($output);//259
}
```

Comment: on line 259 в Capture.php, что на этой строчке-то?

Comment: @Skrillexazem, добавил. Код ошибки 126 выдается

Comment: скорее всего у вас нет прав на запись файлов, проверьте права на папку

Comment: @AntonKucenko, Права есть.